# Routed google domain emails

Tags: email, google-apps, google-email-settings-api

i have an idea about system where users respond to website's messages using the emails they received.

Is it even possible to have multiple imaginary emails with hash in the e-mail's name field(f.e., 1h2149g0as1gasd9123@mysite.com ) and those all imaginary e-mails just forward content to messaging@mysite.com e-mail. And afterwards we are able to parse the contents and know for which conversation the message was sent.

The emails are hosted in Google service. Could not find any information about this in internet.

Such option would be excellent, because there would be no need of including the identificator in e-mail's content which might be deleted if no quoted text is in replied e-mail.

I'm open to any other suggestions that would fit in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

When using Google's service, you can add [tags after the e-mail address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) using a +.  For example...

- test@domain.com
- test+12345@domain.com
- test+wuishw78@domain.com

will all go through to test@domain.com, and you can then look at the address.

Note this is not supported by all e-mail systems, so while this works on Google's hosted e-mail, it may not work on others.

Comment: This is excellent works perfectly for my need. Although i found an interesting solution while reading Email_Address's wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address). It is possible to add comment in email surrounding it by brackets, but in most cases, that comment was interpreted as sender's name. So i will stick to you suggestion. Thank you